# Shading cells of a grid of "pixels" using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on sort of an Etch-a-Sketch project at the moment. The current issue im facing is how to make each cell of the grid incrementally get darker with every pass of the mouse cursor based on what the opacity of the cell being moused-over is. Currently whenever the cells of the grid are created it sets the background color to black and the opacity to 0, I have a function that I believe pulls the opacity of the current cell on mouseover and ***should*** increase that by 10% `shadeCells()`, however instead of doing that it just sets the opacity to 10% and each recurring pass of the mouse does nothing if the cell already has that 10% shade.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.gridContainer');
const startButton = document.querySelector('.gridCreator');

function createGrid(rows = 16, columns = 16) { // Creates  default grid of 16x16 on page load
  total = rows * columns;

  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    cells = document.createElement('div');
    cells.classList.add('cell');
    cells.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: black; opacity: 0;')
    //cellsToBeShaded = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${columns}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`;
    container.appendChild(cells);
  }
  shadeCells();
}
createGrid();

function newGrid(layout) { // Prompts user for input between 2 and 100 to create new grid of a different size
  const cellCount = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

  for (i = 0; i < cellCount.length; i++) {
    container.removeChild(cellCount[i]);
  }
  do {
    layout = parseInt(prompt('How many columns and rows would you like to play? Pick between 12 and 100!'));
    gridSize = layout * layout;
  } while ((layout < 2 && Number) || (layout > 100 && Number));
  createGrid(layout, layout);
}

function shadeCells() { // Shades grid cells on mouseover
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      //cell.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
      if (cell.style.opacity >= 0.1) {
        cell.style.opacity += 0.1;
      } else {
        cell.style.opacity = 0.1;
      }
    })
  })
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', newGrid);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3%;
}

.headerText {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}

button {
  height: 50%;
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px;
}

.gridContainer {
  margin: auto;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="headerText">Etch-A-Sketch</div>
  <button class="gridCreator">Create Grid</button>
</div>
<div class="gridContainer"></div>
```

(Also https://codepen.io/codesharingaccount/pen/xxPjrMy)

Comment: I brought your code into the question.  It's best to not depend on external sites to host significant parts of your question; link rot can make the question useless to future users (and just annoying for present users, since codepen is requiring a captcha)

Comment: @DanielBeck Is it acceptable to just post full code in the question body? Im use to having to share on an external code processing site to make debugging easier.

Comment: The usual guideline is [mcve] -- include enough of your code to reproduce the issue, and no more. Stack Overflow snippets are close enough to feature parity with sites like codepen and jsfiddle to make links to them basically redundant (it's fine to include them, but ideally the question should be as self-contained as possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to force `cell.style.opacity` to be a Number before doing addition on it; the += isn't working:

`cell.style.opacity = Number(cell.style.opacity) + 0.1;`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.gridContainer');
const startButton = document.querySelector('.gridCreator');

function createGrid(rows = 16, columns = 16) { // Creates  default grid of 16x16 on page load
  total = rows * columns;

  for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    cells = document.createElement('div');
    cells.classList.add('cell');
    cells.setAttribute('style', 'margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: black; opacity: 0;')
    //cellsToBeShaded = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${columns}, 1fr)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${rows}, 1fr)`;
    container.appendChild(cells);
  }
  shadeCells();
}
createGrid();

function newGrid(layout) { // Prompts user for input between 2 and 100 to create new grid of a different size
  const cellCount = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

  for (i = 0; i < cellCount.length; i++) {
    container.removeChild(cellCount[i]);
  }
  do {
    layout = parseInt(prompt('How many columns and rows would you like to play? Pick between 12 and 100!'));
    gridSize = layout * layout;
  } while ((layout < 2 && Number) || (layout > 100 && Number));
  createGrid(layout, layout);
}

function shadeCells() { // Shades grid cells on mouseover
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

  cells.forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      //cell.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
      if (cell.style.opacity >= 0.1) {
        cell.style.opacity = Number(cell.style.opacity) + 0.1; // <-- HERE
      } else {
        cell.style.opacity = 0.1;
      }
    })
  })
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', newGrid);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3%;
}

.headerText {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif
}

button {
  height: 50%;
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px;
}

.gridContainer {
  margin: auto;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="headerText">Etch-A-Sketch</div>
  <button class="gridCreator">Create Grid</button>
</div>
<div class="gridContainer"></div>
```

(Adding to a string concatenates, so you'd have been trying to set an opacity of "0.10.1". Ideally this would throw an error instead of just silently doing nothing, but sadly that is not the world we live in)

Comment: You could also change it for `cell.style.opacity = +cell.style.opacity + 0.1;`

Comment: You could. Generally I prefer not using shortcuts like that, they're harder to read; I'd rather spend a few extra characters to make it easier for whoever's going to be maintaining the code to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks so much @DanielBeck it worked! I didn't even realize you'd need to convert it to a number first but it makes so much sense. Also I agree, short handing things at the expense of readability is generally a bad idea.